# Replace \b in json

Tags: python, json

I'm receiving a json file that begins with : `'b\'{  "key" : ....` I'm attempting to remove the `'b\'` part of the string as it's not valid json.

The json is read using :

```
import urllib.request
link = "http://www...."
with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as url:
    s = str(url.read())
```

My code to replace is :  `replace('\'b\'', '')` but the string  `'b\'{  "key" : ....` remains instead of `{  "key" : ....`

Attempting to recreate the issue excluding the json string :

```
mystr = ' b\'{  '
mystr.replace(' b\'{ ', '')
```

successfully replaces as `' '` is the output.

Comment: use json_loads()

Comment: How did you produce this in the first place? Someone has gone `str(binary_result)` somewhere, and they **should not be doing that to begin with**. There are potentially other problems too, like double-escaping of single quotes in the JSON data.

Comment: Ah, I see, *you* did, by using `str(url.read())`. **Decode** binary data, don't produce a representation. `s = url.read().decode('utf8')`.

Comment: Or rather, get the right content type from the response headers; UTF-8 is often a good assumption but not always. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You yourself are adding that `b` by calling `str()` on the data you get. Just don't do that.

If you do actually need to convert it to a string, you should decode it instead:

```
s = url.read().decode('utf-8')
```

but in fact you can almost certainly pass the bytestring directly to `json.loads()`.

Comment: Instead of hard-conding `utf-8`, use `url.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')`; this takes the character set from the Content-Type header, defaulting to UTF-8 if not explicitly specified.